# Django Autocomplete_Light Error When Adding New Element: Select a valid choice. 21 (a primary key) is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to get Django autocomplete_light (Version: 2.0.0a18) with my installation, along with an "Add New Item" button, right next to the autocomplete field. I am able to use autocomplete on the existing items, and am able create new items using add new button. However, after adding the new item, I keep getting the error saying that its primary key is not one of the available choices.

Can someone please help me figure out what's wrong with this setup ?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return urlresolvers.reverse(
            'skill_update', args=(self.pk,))

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from feedback.models import *
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from functools import partial
from django.template import RequestContext, Context
import autocomplete_light
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})
autocomplete_light.autodiscover()


class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(help_text="Please enter the Start Date: ", widget=DateInput())
    end_date = forms.DateField(help_text="Please enter the End Date: ",widget=DateInput())
    skills = autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField('SkillAutocomplete',help_text="Skills used in this period: ") 

    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Report
        exclude = ["report_owner"]


SkillForm = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Skill)
```

autocomplete_light_registry.py:

```
import autocomplete_light
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from feedback.models import Skill
autocomplete_light.autodiscover()

autocomplete_light.register(Skill,add_another_url_name='skill_create',attrs = {
        'data-autcomplete-minimum-characters': 1,
        'placeholder': 'Start typing skill name ...',
    })
```

skill_form.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Create New Skill" class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"/>
        </form>

        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        {% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the "ModelChoiceField" to "ModelMultipleChoiceField" and that got rid of the error. I don't understand the complete mechanics of the solution yet, but am posting it here, in case anyone runs into this issue.